# cubeset function with 2 conditions

Tags: excel, mdx, powerpivot

I am using cubeset function with one condition that is giving me the desired set:

`=CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel";"[ORDERS].[CLIENT].&["&B2&"]*[ORDERS].[ORDERSID].children";"ORDER_ID")`

But I would like to use 2 conditions but the expression is not working:

`=CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel";"[ORDERS].[CLIENT].&["&B2&"].[ORDERS].[PRODCOD].&["&B3&"]*[ORDERS].[ORDERSID].children";"ORDER_ID")`

What is the correct mdx expression to get the result set I need ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418708/cubeset-function-in-excel-with-multiple-criteria

Comment: I have looked already into this example but I can't work it out for my problem. The examples is not referencing other cells...